# changing the background of a page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

how would I dim a background of a page using jQuery?

I have the jQuery code looking like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
      $("body").fadeTo(1000, 0.33);        
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you 'dim' the `body` of the page you'll be dimming every element on the page, as *every* element is, by definition, a child of the `body` element. Particularly if you're using opacity (as `fadeTo()` does).

If you only want to dim the background-image of the `body` element, I'd suggest wrapping another element around the page-content and using a partially-transparent `.png` as a background-image for that element, or use an `rgba()` background-color.

1. [JS Fiddle `background-color` proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XsamG/).
2. [JS Fiddle `background-image` proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XsamG/1/).

Answer (score 1):

you can create a div tag which covers the body, set its back-ground color as black, with opacity of, say 0,7, reducing opacity of the body will change opacity of all elements;

```
  $('#cover').fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out for nice actions on images using the jquery plugin

http://jobyj.in/adipoli/#demo